# How to run more than 4 integration test files in one single dart file in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter-test

When I try to add all main methods in single script and try running it using below command. It displays error as "did not complete"
flutter test -d emulator-xxxx integration_test\app_test.dart

When I try to include multiple dart files(more than 4) in single file as below. The integration scripts are not running and console displays "did not complete"

Suppose I have built my integration_tests folder with multiple dart files(more than 4 dart files) based on functionality of the mobile app

When I create one single file as app_test.dart as below:

`

```
import './test.login.successfull.dart' as LoginTest;
import './test.mainMenu.dart' as mainMenu;
import './test.homePage.dart' as homePage;
import './test.filters.dart' as filters;
import './test.streaming.dart' as streaming;

void main() {
  testAll();
}

Future<void> testAll() async {
  group('All TestCase at Once: ', () {
   
    LoginTest.main();
    mainMenu.main();
    homePage.main();
    filters.main();
    streaming.main();
  });
```

`

**same code works with 4 files**

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is incorrect.

Create four separate test files using the convention:

xxxx_test.dart

Each has a main method with the nested test functions.

Then run
'''
dart test
'''
There is no need to create a script that calls the other tests as the dart test command runs all xxx_test.dart scripts found under the test folder.